# Is it possible to filter data via adjusting the URL address?

Tags: html, sql, r, json, tableau-api

I would need to extract some numbers from following table:

[COVID-19 table](https://datahub.io/core/covid-19/r/1.html)

I need to display it as a supporting table in Tableau. I know I can download it as an .csv, import it in SQL/Tableau and then display it in Tableau but that is too much effort for what I need. Ideally I would like to display/filter directly from Tableau as an iframe or something. Is it possible to filter the data somehow by adding some attributes to the URL address?

Is this somehow possible, I don't know anything about R?

The whole purpose is to not download manually a csv file to have the workbook updated. This would be the easiest way. Do you have any other idea how to get this table to Tableau easily?

Thank you!

Comment: why is R tagged in this question. This is a tableau question, correct?

Comment: The source table is written using R, isn’t it?